# Find a string in XML

Tags: c#, xml, string

I would like to know how to find a string in XML file.

Say this is the XML file i have (these are the SQL server instances btw, irrelevant)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Servernames>
    <loc country="Lockheed">
        <Servername>instance1\server1</Servername>
        <Servername>instance2\server2</Servername>
        <Servername>10.90</Servername>
    </loc>
    <loc country="SouthAmerica">
        <Servername>Hide your heart</Servername>
        <Servername>Bonnie Tyler</Servername>
        <Servername>10.0</Servername>
    </loc>
    <loc country="Britian">
        <Servername>Greatest\Hits</Servername>
        <Servername>Dolly\Parton</Servername>
        <Servername>this\is</Servername>
    </loc>
</Servernames>
```

So what happens is i get a string from the user in any format say for example i only get instance and then i want the listbox to display all the servernames that start with server in the above case it will be

instance1\server1
instance2\serve2

and so on..
Not sure how to achieve this, do i have to open stream reader or just get a string and browser thru the xml file?

UPDATED

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Clear();
    string fileName = "c:\\users\\xxxx\\documents\\visual studio 2010\\Projects\\WpfApplication2\\WpfApplication2\\XML.xml";

        var doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
        var findString = "Server";

        var results = doc.Element("Servernames").Descendants("Servername").Where(d => d.Value.Contains(findString)).Select(d => d.Value);
        listBox1.Items.Add(results.ToString());
        textBox1.Text = results.ToString();
}
```

i am simply getting this in the text box :*System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Xml.Linq.XElement,System.String]*

[image]

**strong text**UPDATE2

.cs file code

private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Clear();

```
        string fileName = "c:\\users\\xxxxx\\documents\\visual studio 2010\\Projects\\WpfApplication2\\WpfApplication2\\XML.xml";

        var doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
        var findString = "Server";

        var results = doc.Element("Servernames").Descendants("Servername").Where(d => d.Value.Contains(findString)).Select(d => d.Value);

        Servers = new ObservableCollection<string>(results);

        MessageBox.Show("THis is loaded");

    }
```

XAML looks like this

```
<ListBox   Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="200,44,0,0" x:Name="ListBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="237">
```

[image]

Comment: You need to use an XDocument, not an XPathDocument.  See updated answer below.

Comment: enumerate on `results` for ex., `String.Join("\n",results)`

Comment: nothing is being displayed if change the code to this. 
listBox1.Items.Add(String.Join("\n",results));
            textBox1.Text = String.Join("\n", results);

Comment: Hi @L.B how to use the enum in my code?

Comment: The search is case sensitive.  Make `findString` "server" instead of "Server".  If you need a case insensitive search, then your "Where" becomes `.Where (d => d.Value.ToLower().Contains(findString.ToLower()))`

Comment: even tried the smaller case as well

Comment: wat could be wrong? can i send u the project or something so u can see for your self?

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/?1r1mndidfr9bc78

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this, assuming you load the XML into an XDocument.

```cs
string fileName = "c:\\users\\xxxxx\\documents\\visual studio 2010\\Projects\\WpfApplication2\\WpfApplication2\\XML.xml";

var doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
var findString = "server";

var results = doc.Element("Servernames").Descendants("Servername").Where (d => d.Value.Contains(findString)).Select (d => d.Value);
```

*Edit - WPF Example*

XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemSource="{Binding Servers}"/>
```

DataContext:

```cs
public ObservableCollection<string> Servers {get; set;}

string fileName = "c:\\users\\xxxxx\\documents\\visual studio 2010\\Projects\\WpfApplication2\\WpfApplication2\\XML.xml";

var doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
var findString = "server";

var results = doc.Element("Servernames").Descendants("Servername").Where (d => d.Value.Contains(findString)).Select (d => d.Value);

Servers = new ObservableCollection<string>(results);
```

**Edit2 - WPF Example without datacontext.  You may want to read up on MVVM approach, as it is becoming the standard for WPF devleopment.  Use this in the interim.**

XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox1" />
```

DataContext:

```cs
string fileName = "c:\\users\\xxxxx\\documents\\visual studio 2010\\Projects\\WpfApplication2\\WpfApplication2\\XML.xml";

var doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
var findString = "server";

var results = doc.Element("Servernames").Descendants("Servername").Where (d => d.Value.Contains(findString)).Select (d => d.Value);

foreach(string result in results)
{
     ListBox1.Items.Add(result);
}
```

Comment: i am getting error at the above (my question updated with code)

Comment: I did the same as u said i even updated but not sure why it is not working is there anything else i need to do?

Comment: @JackyBoi - to populate the ListBox, you need to add each item.  I think you can use the ForEach LINQ statement in this approach.  What do you want the TextBox to contain?  As of your update, you are setting it to the ToString() of results which is System.Linq.IEnumerable.

Comment: ok actually i just want to display the matching items in the listbox rather than the textbox that is much better..tks

Comment: What kind of listbox, winforms, WPF, ASP.Net?

Comment: See a somewhat hacky example.

Comment: umm still nothing displayed for some reason i have updated my code in the original post (after update2)

Comment: Ok.  You're not using an MVVM approach.  Give me a minute and check for update.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10056/discussion-between-jackyboi-and-robaticus)

Comment: Still nothing, so i insert a breakpoint and try to see wat is inside the results and this is what it shows (see the updated picutre in my post)

Comment: i basically got it wrong in my xml file it doesnot have the string that i am finding

Answer (score 1):

You can use XmlDocument like this:

```
string xml = "<your xml>";
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
foreach (XmlNode xmlLoc in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("loc"))
{
    foreach (XmlNode xmlServername in xmlLoc.SelectNodes("Servername"))
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Servername={0}", xmlServername.InnerText));
        // xmlServername.InnerText will be \instance1\server1, etc.
        // UPDATE: add item to listbox
        listBox1.Items.Add(xmlServername.InnerText);
    }
}
```

Comment: ok actually i just want to display the matching items in the listbox rather than the textbox that is much better..tks